# Downgrading from net6 to net5 returns a 500.30 error: cannot find system.runtime v6.0.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-6.0, .net-5

I've deployed a site to IIS with `<TargetFramework>net6</TargetFramework>` and it works as expected on **both** my machine (debugging from VS) and when deployed to my prod server.

For reasons, I needed to downgrade to `<TargetFramework>net5</TargetFramework>` and it again works as expected on my machine (debugging from VS), but now fails with "500.30 - asp.net core app failed to start".

The error (edited for brevity):

`CoreCLR version 5.0.1422.5710 .NET version: 5.0.14`

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0..`

the server has microsoft.aspnetcore and microsoft.netcore runtimes 3 - 6 and no sdk's

my dev machine has microsoft.aspnetcore, microsoft.netcore and microsoft.windowsdesktop sdks and runtimes form  3 - 6

I'm using the same azure pipeline to build and release with the exception that I changed the "Use .NET Core" task to require sdk 5.x from 6.x

What am I possibly overlooking? This **should** be simple.

Comment: Have you downgraded installed packages? Maybe one of them requires newer runtime?

Comment: I downgrade the packages that broke when building but how do I determine which packages are dependent upon a specific assembly.  As in an automated way I know how to use ilspy

Comment: Some (not all) packages have versioning convention to match the runtime version. You can start from those. Also you can check in source control which packages were updated during migration to .NET 6.

Comment: The issue was with swashbuckle.ASPnetcore version 6.4. downgraded to 5.*